# How can I get the AUTO_INCREMENT value in Sequel?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

In MySQL, I can get the auto-increment value by:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

How do I query this information in Sequel? When I tried `DB.run` and `DB.get`, it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else, Sequel makes it easy to send raw SQL:

```
DB["SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'"]
```

From [the documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Using+raw+SQL):

> Using raw SQL
>
> ```
> DB.run "CREATE TABLE users (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, age INT(3) NOT NULL)"
> dataset = DB["SELECT age FROM users WHERE name = ?", name]
> dataset.map(:age)
> DB.fetch("SELECT name FROM users") do |row|
>   p row[:name]
> end
> ```